# vscode Maven Java Project Test are running successfully using mvn command but failing when run from the "Testing" explorer

Tags: visual-studio-code, testing, junit

When I use maven to run tests with this command it works fine:

```
mvn test -f "c:\path\to\pom.xml"
```

But when I run the test using the "Testing Explorer" in vscode, it fails with this error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: path/to/package/ClassName
 at path.to.package.ClassName.TestName(TestFileName.java:15)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: path.to.package.ClassName
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:387)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
 at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:355)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
 ... 24 more
```

It appears that the test doesn't find the required dependencies when it runs. However, the required dependencies for the test method are available and I can see them in other folders under the project but not under the target folder.

Perhaps the question is how to specify the class path when running the tests from the vscode Testing Explorer view.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to create a customized test launch configuration in the settings. There you can specify the classpaths to be appended. See: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-java-test/wiki/Run-with-Configuration